# How to sumif values (days worked) to each month, across a range of multiple weeks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[enter link description here][1]Im trying to arrive at the amount of days worked in a calendar month, over multiple weeks (in their own separate columns). The days are grouped by a week commencing date hence the challenge (any particular week could span across two different months). I have 2 different formulas which I would like to combine or replace with a more concise / efficient one.

The first (below), sums the amount of days which lie in single particular week, across the (1 or 2) different months it crosses over:

```
=IFERROR(IF($B$4>EDATE(J$5,1),0,MAX(,IFERROR(IF(MIN(($B$4+$B$6),MIN(EDATE(J$5,1),($B$4+$B$6)))=J$5-1,0,MIN(($B$4+$B$6),MIN(EDATE(J$5,1),($B$4+$B$6)))),"""")-MAX($B$4,J$5))),0)
```

The second (below) sumifs the total days across the range, although it only uses the week commencing date and inaccurately allocates all of the days to month the W/C date lies in:

```
=(SUMIFS(B5:G5,B3:G3,">="&B$15,B3:G3,"<="&EOMONTH(B$15,0)))
```

Here is a link to the
[workings / spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuHW0Ei2cpLM71p8m3VaScpZB0pQiciLJ90bitx1Qck/edit#gid=0)

Any advice, tips or links would be greatly appreciated! Or even places to source an expert to help.

Many thanks :)

I was expecting to combine 2 different formulas, an if and sumif to analyse resourcing between weeks and months- the two together were seemingly were challenging.

Comment: Lets say for the week `26 Apr - May 3` there's 2 working days. whats the intended logic to apply on which month they need to be allocated to?! (both in april or both in may or divide 1 each b/w 2 months)

Comment: Thanks the reply! The logic would be to allocate 1 day on the 26th and the 2nd on the 27th. So in general terms allocate the days to the soonest available. For example 5 days total would be all in April and 6 would be 5 in April and 1 May. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

***Updated formula***:

```
=let(Λ,tocol(bycol({$B$1:$K$2;$B3:$K3},lambda(Σ,chooserows(sequence(days(index(Σ,2,),index(Σ,1,))+1,1,Σ,1),sequence(index(Σ,3,))))),1,1),  
             countif(index(eomonth(Λ,)),eomonth(B$17,)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, wow that worked perfectly! I added another row in below-eventually I'd plan to hopefully drag the formula down so that it worked for the lines below. Is there a change I could make to enable this?

Comment: try this in Cell B21 to drag side-ways and downwards: `=arrayformula(let(a,flatten(bycol({$B$1:$K$2;$B3:$K3},lambda(z,if(sequence(index(z,3,),1,1,0)=1,sequence(days(index(z,2,),index(z,1,))+1,1,index(z,1,),1),)))),
 countif(eomonth(a,),eomonth(B$15,))))`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Im not sure if it's possible, but do you know of an adjustment to the formula that would allow for additional days to be entered. For example, currently the columns are broken down into weeks (7 days) and ideally it would be great if an 8 was entered for a week, then the allocation per day would be 8/7 = 1.14. The reason for this is that sometimes, in busy periods people would work longer days / overtime. Many thanks again!

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow hope you're well and thanks again for helping a while ago! I recently tested the formula and when I pulled it down and applied to new lines, there seemed to be differences appearing. Each difference was a multiple of 6 which was strange. Please could you take another quick look (I changed the link above to a new sheet showing the differences). Many thanks for your help! Matt (the new spreadsheet URL is also below) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuHW0Ei2cpLM71p8m3VaScpZB0pQiciLJ90bitx1Qck/edit#gid=0

Comment: Is 'Difference' column you added in the sheet is the variance you are seeing between top table data and formula output table?!

Comment: Yes that's correct, all of the days within weeks at the top should fall within the months below, but there seems to be a difference on each line (just highlighted those blue). For example I highlighted in yellow 4 days allocated to the month of June, where I would think, as per the weekly tally above, it to be zero? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer with fresh formula. Difference is zero now all across. Please do test it out.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. Thanks so much again, it's really a big help!

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow just put the formula into action and it works great, apart from one detail, it ignores decimals and only includes whole numbers , do you know if there is a way of tweaking the formula to include the fractions too? I have added fractions to the weekly data table so the fractions show up as differences in the monthly table below it. The link to the sheet is below, any advice would be really appreciated. Thank you https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuHW0Ei2cpLM71p8m3VaScpZB0pQiciLJ90bitx1Qck/edit#gid=0